# .setPostData jqgrid not working

Tags: jqgrid

I want to reload jqgrid with new parameters.I'm using .setPostData().Please look at my code below.It always give me error at .setPostData().M I missing something? format?

```
$('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BBGrid"]').jqGrid({ 
    url:'/Controls/Advertiser/BBControlNew.ascx.ashx?action=getBBData&advertiserID=' + $('#advertiser_id').text() + '&startDate=' + $('input[id$="' + tabID +
 '_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val() + '&endDate=' + $('input[id$="' + tabID + '_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(),
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST', 
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%',
    colNames: result.colNamesData, 
    colModel: result.colModelData,
    //pager: '#RequestLeadspager', 
    rowNum : 100,
    shrinkToFit :false,
...........
function  BuyBackGridReload(tabID,NoSelectedValues)
{
    $('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackGrid"]').setPostData({
        advertiserID:$('#advertiser_id').text(),
        CampaignsDdlSelectedValue: $('select[id$="CampaignDdl"] option:selected').val(),
        startDate: $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(),
        endDate: $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(),
        NoSelectedValue: NoSelectedValues
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
};
```

I have search btn.I'm getting values for NoSelectedValues inside that search btn. here is the code for button click.
$('input[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackSearchBtn"]').click(function(){

```
var values = [];

$('div[id$="' + tabID + '_SelectedBuyBackFilterDiv"] .children').each(function (){
     $(this).find('option').each(function (){
       var attr = $(this).attr('rel');
       if (typeof attr == 'undefined' ){
         values.push($(this).val());
       }
     });
});
BuyBackGridReload(tabID,values);
```

}); //End search click

ERROR:

> $("table[id$=\"" + tabID +
>   "_BuyBackGrid\"]").setPostData({advertiserID:
>   $("#advertiser_id").text(),
>   CampaignsDdlSelectedValue:
>   $("select[id$=\"CampaignDdl\"]
>   option:selected").val(), startDate:
>   $("input[id$=\"" + tabID +
>   "_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx\"]
>   ").val(), endDate: $("input[id$=\"" +
>   tabID + "_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx\"]
>   ").val(), NoSelectedValue:
>   NoSelectedValues}) is undefined

I also don't want to pass as a querystring for new parameters.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `setPostData` to set the `postData` parameter. You can use `setGridParam` function instead. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.8_to_4.0.0) examples.

I suppose if you will use `postData` parameter which contain functions you will not need to set any `postData` parameter at all. The `url` and `postData` parameters of jqGrid can look like

```
url:'/Controls/Advertiser/BBControlNew.ascx.ashx",
postData: {
    action: "getBBData"
    advertiserID: function() { return $('#advertiser_id').text(); },
    startDate: function() { return $('input[id$="' + tabID + '_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
    endDate: function() { return $('input[id$="' + tabID + '_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
    advertiserID: function() { return $('#advertiser_id').text(); },
    CampaignsDdlSelectedValue: function() { return $('select[id$="CampaignDdl"] option:selected').val(); },
    startDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
    endDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
    NoSelectedValue: function() { return NoSelectedValues; }
}
```

The variables `tabID` and `NoSelectedValues` must be defined before. On every grid reloading the function from every `postData` property will be called and you can read **the current** values from the corresponding controls.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. setGridParam works fine. Here is the code. $('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackGrid"]').jqGrid('setGridParam', {postData:{NoSelectedValue:NoSelectedValues} }).trigger("reloadGrid");

Comment: @user659469: Yes it is work, but you can also set `NoSelectedValues` variable which will be used inside of `postData.NoSelectedValue` function. You don't posted enough code, but I suppose you can calculate the value of `NoSelectedValues` directly inside of `NoSelectedValue: function() {/*here*/}`. Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for more infos.

Comment: @Oleg .As per second approach you have suggested,I don't see any param passing to handler. $('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackGrid"]').jqGrid({  url :'/Controls/Advertiser/BuyBackControlNew.ascx.ashx?action=getBuyBackData',
datatype: 'json',mtype: 'POST',postData: {advertiserID: function() { return $('#advertiser_id').text(); }, startDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },endDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); }}
}, I don't see any of these parameters value in firebug. Thanks

Comment: @user659469: Which "param"s you mean? Are `advertiserID`, `startDate` and other parameter will not send to the server? Probably you overwrite there in the `serializeGridData` event handle? If the problem is not yet solved you should append your question with more full definition of the jqGrid which you use.

Comment: @Oleg: I have edited original question. So now you will figure out how & from where I'm getting NoSelectedValues. When I click "search btn" , I need to pass new parameters to server. Thanks.

Comment: @Oleg: please see this link for details question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810885/postdata-not-passing-any-parameters

Comment: @user659469: You can define `var values` outside of `.click` handle and use it in both the `.click` handle and the function `NoSelectedValue` inside of `postData`. Moreover if you do want use `setGridParam` with `postData` you should **not overwrite** the old value. Instead of that you should get the current value with `var pd = $('#yourGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData')`, then extend the `pd` with `$.extend(pd,{NoSelectedValue:NoSelectedValues});`. The setting of `$('#yourGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', 'postData', pd)` are mostly not needed because `pd` will be returned as the reference

Comment: @Oleg:var pd = $('#yourGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'), then extend the pd with $.extend(pd,{NoSelectedValue:NoSelectedValues}); If I don't use setGridParam as you said "The setting of $('#yourGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', 'postData', pd) are mostly not needed because pd will be returned as the reference" then how to reload grid withouy setGridParam?

Comment: @user659469: I answered to your main problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810885/postdata-not-passing-any-parameters/5811359#5811359).