# postData not passing any parameters!

Tags: jqgrid

I'm not able to see any parameters value passing to server in firebug. Here is the code.

```
//BuyBackGridInit() start

function BuyBackGridInit(tabID){


        $('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackGrid"]').jqGrid({   
            url :'/Controls/Advertiser/BuyBackControlNew.ascx.ashx?action=getBuyBackData',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST', 
            height:'100%',
            width:'100%',
            colNames: result.colNamesData, 
            colModel: result.colModelData,
            postData: {
              advertiserID: function() { return $('#advertiser_id').text(); },
              CampaignsDdlSelectedValue: function() { return $('select[id$="CampaignDdl"] option:selected').val(); },
              startDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
              endDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); }
            },
            rowNum : 100,
            shrinkToFit :false,
            altRows: true,
            altclass:'altRow',
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: true,
            gridComplete:function (){
              var recs = parseInt( $('table[id$="'+tabID+'_BuyBackGrid"]').getGridParam("records"),10);
              if (recs == 0){ 
                  $('div[id$="'+tabID+'_NoDataFoundBuyBackdiv"]').show();
                  $('input[id$="AddToCartBtn"]').hide();
                  $('input[id$="BuyBackDownloadBtn"]').hide();
              }
              else {
                  $('div[id$="'+tabID+'_NoDataFoundBuyBackdiv"]').hide();
                  $('input[id$="AddToCartBtn"]').show();
                  $('input[id$="BuyBackDownloadBtn"]').show();
              }
            },
            serializeGridData: function (data){ 
               return $.toJSON(data);   
            }
        });//end of jQuery("#BuyBackGrid").jqGrid()

}//BuyBackGridInit() End
```

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You current implementation of `serializeGridData` just **remove** all functions parameters from the `postData`. So you should either extend `data` parameter inside of `serializeGridData` instead of the usage of `postData`. Another way is to modify `serializeGridData` to the following:

```
serializeGridData: function (data){
    var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
    for (propertyName in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
            propertyValue = data[propertyName];
            if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
            } else {
                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue
            }
        }
   }
   return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
}
```

In the code above we enumerate all properties and call all functions explicitly. Moreover I prefer to use `JSON.stringify` function from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). The function will be native implemented in many web browsers.

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user659469.htm).

Comment: @Oleg : I have replaced my serializeGridData with your piece of code. Now I can see parameters passing to server in firebug. It works fine. But it doesn't change value.It's keep getting old values from controls.I thought postData: part should take care of this. But It didn't. Thanks

Comment: @user659469: You wrote "But it doesn't change value. It's keep getting old values from controls". Sorry, but I don't understand which conrols and which values you mean. Moreover you don't posted any time the HTML which you use.

Comment: @Oleg : I mean to say control values which I'm setting as parameters inside postData part.  postData: {
              advertiserID: function() { return $('#advertiser_id').text(); },
              CampaignsDdlSelectedValue: function() { return $('select[id$="CampaignDdl"] option:selected').val(); },
              startDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_FromCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); },
              endDate: function() { return $('input[id$="'+tabID+'_ToCalBuyBack_CalendarTbx"] ').val(); }
            }, CampaignsDdlSelectedValue,endDate,startDate all these don't change!

Comment: @user659469: Why you mean that jqGrid should **change** contain of any controls which are outside of the grid?

Comment: @Oleg: I thought we are discussing about the controls values outside the grid! I see what you saying. But I want to pass new values to server for the controls outside jqgrid. Like date range(textbox), campaignID(dropdown) which are outside the jqgrid.

Comment: @user659469: With respect of functions inside of `postData` you archive that **the current value** from the controls outside of jqGrid will be read and send to the server. What I don't understand is: "But it doesn't change value. It's keep getting old values from controls". What changes and when you are wait for?

Comment: @Oleg: "But it doesn't change value.It's keep getting old values from controls" - On page load when the call makes to server very first time  using this url :'/Controls/Advertiser/BuyBackControlNew.ascx.ashx?action=getBuyBackData', along with that postData: it passes the right values for all controls outisde the jqgrid. But when I click "search btn"(outise the grid), & if I changes date range, dropdown value for campaign, it doesn't read new values from that controls & just passes the previous value.I hope you are getting me now.

Comment: @user659469: I found the error in my previous code. See updated code and the demo in the modified text of my answer.

Comment: @user659469: You are welcome! I find better to clear all questions. There are really bug in my first suggestion. It's good that the bug was fixed at the end. Best wishes!

Comment: @user659469: By the way starting with 15 points of reputation you have **right to vote questions or answers** (not only answers on your question). It is one of the most important rights. The searching engine use voting to find and to sort the questions. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) you can read how to use voting for answers on your questions. Other interesting informations you can find if you look through [FAQs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @Oleg: Sure. I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: I want to know which grid is better asp.net datagrid (gridview ) OR Jqgrid ? And why?
Thanks,
A