# passing data from jqGrid to webmethod

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

This is my jqGrid calling web method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'product_brow.aspx/ProdGrid',
        postData: {
            ddlproductstatus: function() {
                return  $("#<%=ddlProductStatus.ClientID%>").val();
            },
            ddlproducttype: function() {
                return  $("#<%=ddlProductType.ClientID%>").val();
            }, 
            txtkeywordsearch: function() {
                return  $("#<%=txtKeywordSearch.ClientID%>").val();
            },
            hdnMerchantId: function() {
                return  $("#<%=hdnmerchantId.ClientID%>").val();
            }
        },
        mtype: 'POST',
        serializeEditData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        } ,
        colNames: ['Code', 'Title', 'Price', 'Product Group', 'Edit', 'Status'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 15, align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 40, align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 55 },
            { name: 'Product Group', index: 'Product Group', width: 55 },
            { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 40 },
            { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 40}],
        pager: '#prod_pager',
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'Code',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        rowNum: 10,
        loadtext: "Loading....",
        shrinkToFit: true,
        multiselect: true,
        emptyrecords: "No records to view",
        width: x - 40,
        height: 230,
        rownumbers: true,
        subGrid: true,
        caption: 'Products'
        // editurl: 'Departments.aspx' 
    });
    jQuery("#prodgrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#prod_pager',
        { edit: false, add: false, del: true, excel: true, search: false });
});
```

as you can see im trying to pass data from here to web method with parameters like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ProdDetails(string ddlproductstatus,
                                 string ddlproducttype,
                                 string txtkeywordsearch,
                                 string hdnMerchantId)
{
    StringBuilder sbReturnJson = new StringBuilder();
    string strReturnJson = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder sbCell = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        string sort = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["sidx"].ToString();
        string strSortDerection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["sord"].ToString();
        int iPage = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["page"]);//get the requested page
        string strLimit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["rows"].ToString(); // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
        string strStart = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(strLimit) * (iPage - 1));
        string strEnd = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(strStart) + int.Parse(strLimit));

        string pageNo = string.Empty;
        ProductDal oProductDal = new ProductDal();

        // bind data to gridview

        System.Data.DataTable oDataTable;

        if (txtkeywordsearch.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            oDataTable = oProductDal.GetAllProductDtToDisplayTest(Convert.ToInt32(hdnMerchantId), ddlproducttype,
                ddlproductstatus, iPage, Convert.ToInt32(strLimit));
        }
        else
        {
            oDataTable = oProductDal.GetAllProductDtToDisplayBySearchStringTest(Convert.ToInt32(hdnMerchantId), ddlproducttype,
              ddlproductstatus, txtkeywordsearch.Trim(), iPage, Convert.ToInt32(strLimit));
        }

        // keep values in session to use in product detail page to retrieve records.
        //Session["ProductType"] = ddlproducttype;
      //  Session["ProductStatus"] = ddlproductstatus;

        if (txtkeywordsearch.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
           // Session["SearchKeyword"] = txtkeywordsearch;
        }


        //  hlnkExportToExcel.Visible = false;

        // calculate the total number of records.
        int totalRows = 0;

        if (txtkeywordsearch.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            totalRows = oProductDal.CountAllProductDtToDisplay(Convert.ToInt32(hdnMerchantId), ddlproducttype,
                    ddlproductstatus);
        }

        else
        {
            totalRows = oProductDal.CountAllProductDtToDisplayBySearchString(Convert.ToInt32(hdnMerchantId), ddlproducttype,
                    ddlproductstatus, txtkeywordsearch.Trim());
        }

        //if (!IsPostBack)
        //{
        //    gvProductBrow.PageIndex = _currentPageNumber;
        //}


        var count = oDataTable.Rows.Count;

        sbReturnJson.Append("{\"page\":\"" + iPage + "\",\"records\":\"" + count + "\",\"rows\":[");
        foreach (DataRow row in oDataTable.Rows)
        {
            // int depid = Convert.ToInt32(row[1].ToString());
            // var Editbutton = "<img Class='GridEdit' onclick='showjQueryDialog(" + depid + ");' src='Images/edit.jpeg'></img>";
            //<a href='#' Class='GridEdit' onclick='showjQueryDialog(" + depid + ");'>Edit</a>
            string code = (row[1].ToString());
            string title = (row[4].ToString());
            string price = (row[7].ToString());
            string product_group = (row[5].ToString());
            string edit = (row[0].ToString());
            string status = (row[2].ToString());

            sbCell.Append("{\"cell\":[\"" + code + "\",\"" + title + "\",\"" + price + "\",\"" + product_group + "\",\"" + edit + "\",\"" + status + "\"]}");
            sbCell.Append(",");
        }

       // lblNoOfRows.Text = totalRows + " record(s) found";

        sbReturnJson.Append(sbCell.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
        double dCount = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(count / int.Parse(strLimit)));
        int iCount = int.Parse(dCount.ToString()) + 1;
        sbReturnJson.Append("],\"total\":\"" + iCount + "\"}");

        //lblTopPageNo.Text = (gvProductBrow.PageIndex + 1) + "/" + CalculateTotalPages(totalRows);
        //lblBottomPageNo.Text = (gvProductBrow.PageIndex + 1) + "/" + CalculateTotalPages(totalRows);
        //ViewState["NoOfPages"] = CalculateTotalPages(totalRows);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        //lblErrorMessage.Text += Resources.Resource.Product_errMsgLoadProduct;
        return "Error";
    }
    return sbReturnJson.ToString();  
}
```

my web method is expecting 4 parameters which i am trying to pass using postData but since i am a newbi i dont know how to post data to tht web method from my jqGrid. Need help got stuck with this for around 5 hrs

can you also help with sending the page,sidx,sort from jqgrid to web method

Comment: Why you use ASPX and not a standard ASMX web service? Is it your real requirement or ASMX or even WCF web service could be also welcome on your web site? Which .NET version and Visual Studio you use?

Comment: i have limited permissions and i have never used the webservices and wcf..so can u please help with aspx

Comment: Which .NET version and Visual Studio you use?

Comment: Oleg can u atleast tell me how to pass sidx,sord ,page and rowNum in web method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use ASMX or WCF web service. In the case many things like JSON serialization and deserialization will be made automatically for you. You should just return an object from the web method.

In general WCF RESTfull service has advantages in comparing with ASMX web service, but if you are a beginner you can more easy add ASMX web service to your existing project so that all changes of web.config will made Visual Studio for you.

To add ASMX web service to your existing ASP.NET project you should do following steps. You select your current project in the Solution Explorer (typically on the right side in the Visual Studio) and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or click right mouse button and choose "Add" and the "New Item…") you should choose "Web" template on the left side and then "Web Service". You can change the filename on the bottom from default `WebService1.asmx` to any what you want. For example `ProdData.asmx`. In the `ProdData.asmx.cs` file you should uncomment the line with `[ScriptService]` attribute. You can additionally insert `using System.Web.Script.Services;` at the beginning of the file. Now you can change the code of "Hello world" web method to what you need. For example to

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace TestWebApplicationWithjqGrid
{
    public class GridRow {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<string> cell { get; set; }
    }
    public class GridData {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int records { get; set; }
        public List<GridRow> rows { get; set; }
    }
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding (ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem (false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class ProdData: WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public GridData ProdDetails(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows,
                                    string ddlproductstatus, string ddlproducttype, string txtkeywordsearch, int hdnMerchantId) {
            return new GridData {page = 1, total = 1, records = 2, rows = new List<GridRow> {
                new GridRow {id = "i1", cell = new List<string> {"Code1", "Title1", "Price1", "Group1", "Edit1", "Status1"}},
                new GridRow {id = "i2", cell = new List<string> {"Code2", "Title2", "Price2", "Group2", "Edit2", "Status2"}}
            }};
        }
    }
}
```

You should of course has more complex implementation of the `ProdDetails` web method. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) gives you examples. See additionally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029909/load-data-from-webservice-asmx-to-jqgrid-please-help-me/4031603#4031603) for more links with code examples.

To call the web method from the JavaScript you should modify you jqGrid a little. You should include the following additional parameters

```
datatype: 'json',
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
    for (propertyName in postData) {
        if (postData.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
            propertyValue = postData[propertyName];
            if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
            } else {
                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue
            }
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
},
jsonReader: {
    root: "d.rows",
    page: "d.page",
    total: "d.total",
    records: "d.records"
}
```

The code of `serializeGridData` I get from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810885/postdata-not-passing-any-parameters/5811359#5811359). It is more complex as just

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); }
```

used in the most cases because you use functions inside of `postData`.

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestWebApplicationWithjqGrid.zip) you can download VS2010 .NET 3.5 working project with the corresponding code.

Comment: thanx for your help and time...your answer is really helpful for a noob like me

Comment: @bhargav: You are welcome! How I understand the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) rules you should has the voting right, but I don't know more restrictions as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits/5213#5213). But it's not a problem, the answer has now more as 0 reputation and so it will be interpreted by the searching engine as "helpful". I am grad to hear that my answer and the demo project was helpful for you.