# jqgrid - serializeGridData with additional postData params

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to use serializeGridData to convert my postdata to JSON using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542) from [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg). Here is my code.

```
jQuery(function() {
   $('#grid').jqGrid({
       ........
       ........
       postData: {
        param1: function() { return $("param1").val(); },
        param2: function() { return $("param2").val(); },
        searchText: function() { return $("searchText").val(); },
        totalRecords: function() { return msgGrid.getGridParam("records"); }
    },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
           return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    ajaxGridOptions : {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
    });
});
```

postData coming to serializeGridData does not replace the custom params defined in postData {} with actual values. I have debugged in firebug and this is how the data is coming to serializeGridData method. So eventually JSON.stringify is not converting param1, param2.. values in the request data. How can fix it to send the actual values for custom params? Thanks in advance..

```
_search     false
nd      1349195468864
page        1
rows        25
sidx        "sortcol_name"
sord        "desc"
param1      function()        // expect to have actual param1 value
param2      function()
searchText          function()
totalRecords    function()
```

Comment: Do you tried the code from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5811359/315935)?

Comment: @Oleg: I just tried and working perfect. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should enumerate all properties of `postData` inside of `serializeGridData` callback and use `$.isFunction` inside of it to verify whether some property is a method. In case of method you should call the method and save the result in the property with the same name. Look at the implementation of `serializeRowData` from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365228/315935) or in the code of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296601/315935).

Comment: That worked great. Thanks a lot, you are so helpful. I was just making the changes when you put the comment about if I have tried this answer. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

When `JSON.stringify` encounters a function, it [censors it to null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Try setting the data without functions, like this:

```
postData: {
    param1: $("param1").val(),
    // etc.
}
```