# jqgrid webmethod : failed to save row

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jqgrid, webmethod

ByVal datax As ObjectI'm trying to use ASP.NET with webmethod to retrieve data and save data for jqgrid.
I can retrieve data from the webmethod but no luck to do the save.
The server side seems never get my post data.  Would someone please help?

grid code:

```
$('#list99').jqGrid({
                datatype: function(postdata) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'dbtest.aspx/getdata',
                        editurl: 'dbtest.aspx/updatedb',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: '{}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        error: function(data, textStatus) {
                            alert('Error loading json');
                        },
                        success: function(data, st) {


                            if (st == 'success') {
                                var grid = $("#list99");
                                var gridData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                                grid.clearGridData();
                                for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                                    grid.addRowData(i + 1, gridData[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#list99").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager99', { add: true, edit: true, del: true });

                        }
                    });
                },                
                type: 'POST',
                editurl: 'dbtest.aspx/updatedb',
                colNames: ['customerid', 'customername'],
                colModel: [
                          { name: 'customerid', index: 'customerid', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                          { name: 'customername', index: 'customername', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text'}],
                pager: $('#pager99'),
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [10],
                sortname: 'customerid',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                //width: 300
                autowidth: true

});
```

server side code:

```
Public Class customer

        Public customerid As String
        Public customername As String

    End Class

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function getdata() As String

        Dim c1 As New customer
        Dim c2 As New customer
        c1.customerid = "1"
        c1.customername = "pete"
        c2.customerid = "2"
        c2.customername = "joah"
        Dim lstcustomer As New List(Of customer)
        lstcustomer.Add(c1)
        lstcustomer.Add(c2)

        Dim jsonserial As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim result As String
        result = jsonserial.Serialize(lstcustomer)

        Return result

    End Function

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function updatedb(ByVal datax As Object) As String

        //attempt to do save

    End Function
```

The function updatedb just never being called after i clicked "sumbit" after add/edit/delete.

After that i checked with firebug and i got the error message:

```
"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'data'."
```

I've also tried to add the following:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            recreateForm: true,
            serializeEditData: function(data) {
                //alert('in2');
                //alert(postData.customerid);
                //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
                if (data.customerid == undefined) { data.customerid = null; }
                var postData = { 'data': data };
                //alert(postData.customerid);
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            }
        });
```

It still didnt work  =(

Comment: Do you see the AJAX call go out? Does it contain the post data?

Comment: sorry i'm new to jquery, how can i check if the AJAX call go out?

Comment: yes i've checked with firebug and the AJAX call go out, however i got this error message:

Comment: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you ever use `datatype` defined as function especially if you do just `jQuery.ajax` to communicate with the server. jqGrid provide many ways to customize data which will be send to the server (see `serializeGridData` callback and `ajaxGridOptions` option of jqGrid for example) and to change the server response before the server response will be processed by jqGrid (`beforeProcessing` callback for example). The current code use `addRowData` to fill the data. It' the slowest way to fill the grid which I know. Moreover you call `navGrid` on every loading of the data instead of calling it once directly after the grid will be created. All other calls will be just ignored. You can find many examples how to use web servicing together with jqGrid. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296601/315935) for example

Your current code mix the options of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with [the options of jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). You placed `editurl` option of jqGrid into the list of options of `$.ajax`.

One more important error is the usage of correct names of variables in `updatedb` method. You use currently `datax As Object` instead of usage `customerid` and `customername` as parameters.

Comment: Thanks oleg for the comment, i've solved the problem somehow by matching the parameters' name of "Public Shared Function updatedb" to the response from web.

Comment: The ajax get is bad i know and i'm now trying with url + serializegriddata + jsonreader ... but no luck, keep try..

Comment: @user2045340: You are welcome! Look at the code of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296601/315935) more carefully. I think it shows you how to replace `datatype` as function to `datatype: "json"`. In your case you can just try to modify your JavaScript code to use `datatype: 'json', mtype: "POST", ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json"}, serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(dataToSend); }, jsonReader: { root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" }, loadonce: true`. It should work to fill the grid.